# forval and varlist loop error

Tags: loops, stata

I have an Excel file with years in columns C to BQ (1950 to 2016). I read it in via `import excel` and have a dataset `A` to `BQ`, `C` to `BQ` being the years.

I´d like to rename `C` to `BQ` to `_1950` to `_2016` via the following loop but seem to have it wrong.

```
forval  i=1950/2016 {
    foreach x of varlist C-BQ {
        rename `x' _`i+1'
    }
}
```

`C` gets renamed to `_1950` but Stata throws:

> variable _1950 already defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need loops: see `help rename group` for technique. In your case, here's a simplified example.

```
. ds
A  B  C  D  E

. 
. rename (C-E) _#, addnumber(1950)

. 
. ds
A      B      _1950  _1951  _1952

.
```

Where you went wrong with your double-loop example is that the innermost loop and outermost loop do not increment in tandem.

```
 . forval  i=1950/1952 {
  2. foreach x of varlist C-E {
  3. 
. display `" rename `x' _`i+1' "'
  4. 
.     }
  5. }   
 rename C _1950 
 rename D _1950 
 rename E _1950 
 rename C _1951 
 rename D _1951 
 rename E _1951 
 rename C _1952 
 rename D _1952 
 rename E _1952
```

.

Comment: For a comment on why the OP's attempt at incrementing doesn't work, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here. You need a single loop and the syntax for incrementing the local macro is quite wrong.

The syntax

```
`i+1'
```

is not equivalent to the value of the local macro `i` plus 1.

Try it:

```
. local i = 42

. di "`i+1'"
42
```

What's happening is that Stata ignores the `+1` within the macro reference as trailing garbage, but it does show what's in the macro `i`: it can make sense of that reference. The rule applying here is that the `+` could not be part of a legal macro name.

You could do this to take the local macro, add 1, and show the result:

```
. di "`=`i'+1'"
43
```

See the help for `macro`.

As William Lisowski points out, `rename` will do the renaming for you any way without an explicit loop.

But how would you loop if you did not know that, or if you were using a version of Stata that did support loops but not the extra `rename` facilities introduced in Stata 12? Here's one way:

```
local i = 1950 
foreach x of varlist C-BQ {
    rename `x' _`i'
    local ++i 
}
```

Another way to do it before Stata 12 would be to use `renvars` from the *Stata Journal*

```
renvars C-BQ \ _1950-_2016
```

`renvars` requires Stata 8 up. Naturally, underneath the surface it is executing a loop over your old variables and your new variable names.